# Android getting stuck while building gradle project

Tags: android, build.gradle

While running a project android getting stuck at _debug UnitTest apk.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww3cq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your System Configuration and Minimum system Requirement For android studio.
If Your System Is Proper For Android studio.
Then YOu Check Your SDK location .
and  Go To File menu on Android studio they have a option invalidate cache and restart and press this option . when You invalidate cache and restart then Your Problem is Solved

Comment: Im using android studio in this system almost 1 year.it happens yesterday on wards i un installed th studio and re installed it.but still problem occures

Comment: You Check android studio SDK Location

Comment: If Your android studio Location name not have a space please check one time

Comment: Another wise Contact me I am Help You

Comment: I checked no problem in sdk location name

Comment: Problem still exist

Comment: If Problem Exits You Click on Invalidate and restart